# Unable to disable TextBox on CheckBox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a @Html.TextBox and a @Html.CheckBox, no matter what is entered in @Html.TextBox , the moment I click checkbox for windows authentication I want my @Html.TextBox  to become EMPTY and DISABLED

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div id="emailtext">@Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Email)</div>
  <div id="chk">@Html.CheckBox("CheckWindowsAuth") @Html.Label("Use windows authntication")</div>
}
```

My jquery which is not helpinng

```
<script src="my jquery path"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chk").click(function(){
       $("#emailtext").val("");
       $("#emailtext").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    });
 });   
</script>
```

Please help me know where I'm going wrong...
Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't `$("#emailtext")` be the textbox? It should surely be `$("#emailtext input")`. You are referencing the div, not the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the `.val` and `.attr` to the input, not the containing div. This should work:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chk").click(function(){
       $("#Email").val("");
       $("#Email").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    });
 });
```

However, Razor's helper methods are sometimes funky, so you may want to right click and inspect element on the input in the browser and make sure that the id is `Email`.

Answer (score 0):

As per your code, `#chk` is a div and similarly `#emailtext` is also a div.

If the elements are inside the div then you need to change the selector

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chk input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
       $("#emailtext input").val("");
       $("#emailtext input").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
    });
 });
```

You may also need to check the value of the checkbox. Whether it's checked or not before disbaling the input box.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#chk input[type=checkbox]").change(function(){
           if($(this).is(":checked")) {
              $("#emailtext input").val("");
              $("#emailtext input").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
           } else {
                $("#emailtext input").removeAttr("disabled"); 
           }
        });
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think $.click is failing you.

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#chk").change(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(':checked')){
           $("#emailtext input").removeAttr("disabled");  
        }
        else{
           $("#emailtext input").val("");
           $("#emailtext input").attr("disabled", "disabled"); 
        }

    });
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0hwsLs4y/

---

Edit, this above was correct, the ids are on the containers, not the inputs

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use `prop` [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr` [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) as using attr to get or retrieve values has been deprecated fro certain elements since jQuery 1.6.

> As of jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method returns undefined for attributes
>   that have not been set. To retrieve and change DOM properties such as
>   the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the
>   .prop() method.